forming a recurrence relation for painting stripes with restrictions (combinatorics)
I have the following question:

Using three basic colours (Red, Blue, Green) different colours are made by mixing these two or more colours in equal proportion. Then n vertical stripes are painted by all colours available.
The number of ways of painting these stripes so that no two consecutive stripes have any basic color common is denoted by t(n). Form a recurrence relation for t(n).

Kindly provide solution

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

If it's paint, I would go for red, blue, yellow rather than red, blue, green. Not that that's relevant to the actual problem.


This question isn't clear. Please give an example. 2) This will oblige you to work on your subject...


Kindly provide your working and particular difficulty.
